# Localizing Default Error Messages in ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I used this HOWTO for how to use localization for error messages:

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form

Basically you have to add the following piece of code in your Application_Start() method in Global.asax:

```
 ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
 DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
```

Right click your ASP.NET MVC project in Solution Explorer inside Visual Studio and select Add => Add ASP.NET Folder => App_GlobalResources.

Now add a `.resx` file inside this folder called `Messages.resx.`

Finally add the following string resources in that .resx file:

```
Name                   Value
====                   =====
FieldMustBeDate        The field {0} must be a date.
FieldMustBeNumeric     The field {0} must be a number.
PropertyValueInvalid   The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
PropertyValueRequired  A value is required.
```

You should be good to go.

This works fine for MVC4 but now I made an upgrade to MVC5.2.3 and nothing works any more! WHY?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but try a name other than `Messages` for your resources file? I have the exact same setup (my file is called `MvcValidation`) in an application running 5.2.3 and it's working fine.

Comment: I renamed Messages to MvcValidation but is still the same :(

Comment: Try DefaultModelinder.ResourceKey https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs#L495-L498

Comment: hmm what do you mean with default?